# MATLAB - Undefined variable or class while following help example

Tags: matlab, tracking, motion, matlab-cvst

I'm following Motion-Based Multiple Object Tracking from [mathworks.com/help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/motion-based-multiple-object-tracking.html)
Matlab r2013b gives me an error `Undefined variable or class "obj.reader.step"` when I try to execute main function. I'm using copy-pasted functions and a custom avi file, which seems to be valid.
The code fragment is

```
function frame = readFrame()
        frame = obj.reader.step();
    end
```

Where the obj is being set up like that

```
obj.reader = vision.VideoFileReader('sample.avi');

obj.videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer('Position', [20, 400, 700, 400]);
obj.maskPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer('Position', [740, 400, 700, 400]);

obj.detector = vision.ForegroundDetector('NumGaussians', 3, ...
    'NumTrainingFrames', 40, 'MinimumBackgroundRatio', 0.7);

obj.blobAnalyser = vision.BlobAnalysis('BoundingBoxOutputPort', true, ...
    'AreaOutputPort', true, 'CentroidOutputPort', true, ...   
    'MinimumBlobArea', 400);
```

Full code is in the link. I believe it is a simple problem, but I didn't use matlab for a long time. May this be the video codec?
Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form the top of the page you linked to:

> This example is a function with the main body at the top and helper routines in the form of [nested functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/rmvd_matlablink__01bc6576b6a8c3e1749bb2f9c8507d4e.html) below.

In other words the `readFrame` function is meant to be a nested function inside of the function where you create your `obj.reader` object. Alternatively, you could pass in `obj.reader` as an argument. If you look at the code that generated the `obj.reader` object (`setupSystemObjects`), it is also a nested function, but it returns `obj` to the outer main function. By the way, if you want to view all of the code together in the Matlab editor, just type `edit multiObjectTracking` in command window.

[Nested functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html?s_tid=doc_12b) have access to all of the variables (workspace) of the outer function. [This blog post](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/programming-patterns-nested-functions-in-matlab.html) discusses them in more detail.

Comment: I understand, but I said I use full code provided by that site, thus I'm calling body of multiObjectTracking() with obj being set up the way I posted.

Comment: First, I assume that you can run the `multiObjectTracking` demo by itself. Then, if you are indeed using the code of `multiObjectTracking` (nested functions, the setup function returns `obj`, etc.). I assume that you're using a `while` loop and that this part executes `while ~isDone(obj.reader)` fine the first time through meaning that `obj.reader` itself exists. The next thing is to ask what version of Matlab/Vision Toolbox you're using and if the code of `edit multiObjectTracking` is the same what you're using from online.

Comment: Double check that you haven't forgotten an `end` in your M-file which can make all of the difference between nested functions and not. The `obj` in `obj.reader.step()` should be colored cyan and you should get a message when you hover over it in the Editor.

Comment: I'm not a clever man. Not at 3am at least. I was storing each of these functions in separate files.